# View not found by Controller - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to web development and have the following exception

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Create' was not found. The following locations were searched:

[Exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RgnD.png)

I have to tried the following Nuget packages (as read on other forums) : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers and Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset but nothing seems to work.

Below is my Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();



app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "champ",
    pattern: "{controller=Champ}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The way my folders are organized :

[Solution folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpBAc.png)

and the corresponding ActionLinks :

```
   @{
                        foreach (var item in Model.listSections)
                        {
                    <table class="table table-sm small " style="background-color:@item.section_color1;">
                <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:25px;">@item.id_section</td>
                                <td class="text-left" style="width:150px;">@item.section_name</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:60px;">@item.section_color1</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:60px;">@item.section_color2</td>
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:30px;">@Html.ActionLink("New","Create","Champ",null)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    foreach (var citem in Model.listChamps.Where(citem => citem.id_section == item.id_section).ToList())
                    {
                        <table class="table table-sm small" style="background-color:@item.section_color2;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width:15px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width:25px;">@citem.id_champ</td>
                                    <td class="text-left" style="width:150px;">@citem.champ_name</td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width:45px;">@citem.is_active</td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width:60px;">@citem.prefix</td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width:30px;">@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit","Champ",null,new {id = citem.id_champ })</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    }
                        }
                    }
```

I have been struggling with that for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated (I have already updated VS 2022 to the latest version also and tried all the solutions seen on forums).

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Please re-read the [MRE] guidance and [edit] post to include text instead of images - at very least for error message, but really list of files can be shown as text (`dir /s /b` is a good way to get text with folder names). While you are at it you may want to check if files actually can be found at locations mentioned in the error message.

Comment: OK - I did not know - thank u
Yes the files are there. I even tried to delete them and recreate from scratch (relaunch VS also) but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Check Views folder in your project
you should have following hierarchy

Views->Champ->Create.cshtml

Comment: Yes...thats's what I have ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by re-adding each view from the controller actions (Create, Edit, Index) in Visual Studio and deleting the previous ones (including the Views/Champ folder).

When doing that, it creates another Views/Champ folder (and you need to manually delete the other one)

Strange.